# Prove $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x)$ is Improper Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

> Prove $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x)$$ is
>   Riemann integrable

I don't understand this function so can you help me or give me some hint please?

Comment: notice that for each x the sum will only have one none zero value

Comment: and it will be the same one for the whole segment: [n-1,n)

Comment: Split t$[0,\infty)$  into a collection of disjoint intervals $I_n=[n-1,n)$. For $x \in I_n$ we have $f(x) = (-1)^n {1 \over n}$. So, it is straightforward to visualise & compute $\int_0^m f(x) dx$.